# android companion app for unity game possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have been thinking about project ideas and I was going to create a unity game that will have various different game metrics stored eg time played, coins collected etc.... and an Android application to connect to that unity game to visualize the metrics on the app, I have been researching this for a while and haven't come across any android companion apps being developed for unity or in general. I would imagine there would be intensive networking involved. any recommendations on how to go about this would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: if you only track data like analytics, you only need a server to post and get the info. Nothing intensive. One app sends info when specific action, the other can be connected via socket to get info real time or simple HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Everts. I was thinking of posting data to a server which hosts a php file and have that send the data back to an android app developed through android studio. I was also thinking along the lines of actually linking an app directly to the game like how dead rising 3 does where the app will show the map of the game or inventory of the player. I haven't found a way to link that to unity